# App crashes when calling a method from viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, viewmodel, kotlin-stateflow

I'm trying to make a request to a remote server using retrofit. I'm using clean architecture for separating concerns.
From the top level files

Retrofit call

```
@GET("/api/dedicated_trips")
    suspend fun getDedicatedTrips(
        @Header("Authorization") token: String,
    ): DedicatedTripDto
```

DedicatedTripDto

```
data class DedicatedTripDto(
    val `data`: List<Data>,
    val error: Boolean
)
```

Data

```
data class Data(
    val depot_location: String,
    val depot_name: String,
    val fuel_amount: Int,
    val fuel_in_litres: Int,
    val fuel_receipt: String?,
    val milleage: Int,
    val no_of_vehicles: Int,
    val odometer_reading: String?,
    val partner_email: String,
    val partner_name: String,
    val pump_reading: String?,
    val registration_number: String,
    val status: String,
    val tracking_no: Int,
    val type: String,
    val vehicle_make: String
)
```

Here is my Usecase

```
class GetDedicatedTripUseCase @Inject constructor(
    private val tripRepository: TripRepository
) {

    suspend operator fun invoke(
        token: String,
    ): Flow<Resource<DedicatedTripDto>> = flow {
        try {
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            val response = tripRepository.getDedicatedTrips(token)
            emit(Resource.Success(response))
        } catch (e: HttpException) {
            emit(Resource.Failure(e.localizedMessage ?: "An expected error occurred"))
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            emit(Resource.Failure("Couldn't connect to server, check your internet connection"))
        }
    }

}
```

Resource

```
sealed class Resource<out T> {
    class Loading<T>: Resource<T>()
    object Empty: Resource<Nothing>()
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T): Resource<T>()
    data class Failure<out T>(val errorMessage: String?): Resource<T>()

    companion object {
        fun <T> loading() = Loading<T>()
        fun <T> success(data: T) = Success(data)
        fun <T> failed(message: String) = Failure<T>(message)
    }
}
```

On the view model side

```
@HiltViewModel
class TripViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getDedicatedTripUseCase: GetDedicatedTripUseCase,
): ViewModel() {

   private var _dedicatedTripsState = MutableStateFlow<Resource<DedicatedTripDto>>(Resource.Empty)
   val dedicatedTripsState get() = _dedicatedTripsState.asStateFlow()

  fun getTrips(
        token: String,
    ) = viewModelScope.launch {
        getDedicatedTripUseCase(token).collect { state->
            when(state) {
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    _dedicatedTripsState.value = Resource.loading()
                }
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    _dedicatedTripsState.value = Resource.success(state.data)
                }
                is Resource.Failure -> {
                    _dedicatedTripsState.value = Resource.failed(state.errorMessage!!)
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

On the View side here is how calling the view model code

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class TripDetailsFragment : Fragment() {

  private val tripViewModel: TripViewModel by viewModels()
   private var token: String? = null

 override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
       tripViewModel.authToken.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            token = "Bearer $it"
           //Here is where I'm invoking the function from the view model
            tripViewModel.getTrips(token!!)
        }
}
}
```

When I call the function, the app crashes without showing any error in the logcat.

Json file

```
{
    "error": false,
    "data": [
        {
            "tracking_no": 18842224,
            "milleage": 56,
            "odometer_reading": "odometer/starting-odometer-18842224.jpg",
            "fuel_amount": 0,
            "fuel_in_litres": 0,
            "pump_reading": null,
            "fuel_receipt": null,
            "type": "starting",
            "status": "closed",
            "no_of_vehicles": 4,
            "depot_name": "MURANGA TOWN (fomer Fort Hall), Kenya",
            "depot_location": "MURANGA TOWN (fomer Fort Hall), Kenya",
            "vehicle_make": "Isuzu",
            "registration_number": "KDP 234A",
            "partner_name": "DHL",
            "partner_email": "info@dafric.net"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Comment: When you use debugger inside `fun getTrips`, in what line does it crash? Maybe `tripViewModel` is not correctly initialized.

Comment: It doesn't log anything.

Comment: The logcat is empty

Comment: When operating correctly, the logcat is *never* empty. Make sure you have selected the right emulator, application, and output mode (try Verbose) and don't have any filters on if it's totally empty, or restart the emulator. Even when the app is running normally there is a ton of output there.

Comment: You could try restarting logcat too, with the button that looks like a square with a looping arrow coming out of it. There's no way an app is crashing without some part of the system logging it. If you're still not seeing anything, try restarting the IDE, and if it's still not working, try the command line: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#Syntax Nobody can really help you unless we know what the actual error is here (post the full stacktrace when you get it!)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have internet permission given in AndroidManifest file?

Are you sure the api is working fine? Maybe it's returning error or something that is in different format.

Try putting logs and/or break-points line by line to find the issue.

Also, maybe some of fields are coming empty and you're not aware of. Try (temporarily) changing all data types to nullable String (String?) and see if it makes a difference.